# CSS with ID attribute not working on LARAVEL 8

Tags: html, css, laravel-8

I have called my css like this `<link href="{{ URL::asset('/assets/css/app.min.css') }}" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

There is `id` on tag css. this css successfully called the directory if my url site no sub domain like laravel.test/example. but the css fails to call if my url site like laravel.test/example/example2..

If i remove that `id`.. it work on all sites. but i need that `id` because its making some feature like change light/dark mode layouts.

So `id='app-style'` is going to file `app.js`.
In `app.js` there is `s("#app-style").attr("href","assets/css/app-dark.min.css")`. `app-dark.min.css` is failure to call..

It will be easy if i can use blade on javascript.

Comment: `id` is not valid on a `link` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: copy sir.. ill try to find other way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question. Because `id='app-style'` is going to file `app.js` and there is some code to call other css..

i just need to change my `app.js` from asset to `app.blade.php` on view and set it on main layout.

now i can change directory structure from blade. `s("#app-style").attr("href","assets/css/app-dark.min.css")` to `s("#app-style").attr("href","{{ asset('assets/css/app-dark.min.css') }}")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use
`asset()` helper function but I'm not sure:

```
<link href="{{ asset('./css/app.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: why there is `.` on directory ?

Comment: i already use asset or URL::asset.. it was same..
its work if i remove that `id`..

Comment: @rendichs You should edit the question to explain what you've already tried, so that people won't suggest things you already know won't fix the problem.

Comment: i already explain this "If i remove that id.. `it work on all sites`."

Comment: Oh sorry i did not know 

so you should try another way to do it, ```id``` attr can not set to a ```link ``` tag,

what are you want exactly do with ```id``` attr?

Comment: yeah, i just buy a template.. so that `id` can change my layout to light/dark mode.. example on template is already available on `link` tag..
its only works on main directory, not working on sub directory..

Answer (score 0):

In your blade you can check if something is or not. The you can include a condition to make the switch. Something like that:

```php
@php
    $hasDarkMode = true;
    $link = $hasDarkMode ? 'app-dark.min.css' : 'app.min.css';
@endphp

<link href="{{ URL::asset('/assets/css/' . $link) }}" 
  rel="stylesheet" 
  type="text/css" />
```

But it probably makes the most sense to make the condition on the href attribute.

Comment: Thank u for reply. Even its on app-style or app-style-dark, when my url going to laravel.test/example/example2 or laravel.test/example/create.. my css will not calling..

Comment: @rendichs it because the condition below dont effected the link.. i updated my answear.

Comment: i got my problem.. its on app.js.. there call a link `s("#app-style").attr("href","assets/css/app-dark.min.css")`..
but im not sure i can use blade on javascript file.
ill update my question..